# Issues with Thinkpad T14 (Gen 4) and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, thinkpad

I recently bought a new Thinkpad T14 (Gen4) with AMD Ryzen 7 pro 7840U. I have a dual boot with Windows 11 (that has no problem) and Ubuntu 22.04.
Ubuntu seems to have a lot of problems: the screen frequently flashes, sometimes it goes black for a fraction of a second, sometime it just glitches, and while it does so if I'm writing it just repeats several time the letter I was typing.
I also use a second monitor and sometimes windows that I have open on my first monitor just switch to the second one.
On rare occasions, after a screen flick, the laptop's screen's brightness drops and won't change.

I know that a friend of mine with a T14 gen3 has similar issues but only on startup and for a few minutes, while my PC sometimes seems to have a stroke and keeps bugging out for a long time.

Since my Windows partition works perfectly fine, I believe that this is an OS issue. Are those problems being addressed in future releases? It seems kinda weird anyway since I'm using a LTS version.

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X? In either case, switch to the other option. I had similar issues with my P14s with Wayland.